# Can't get HAML syntax right for the copy of a form button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, yaml

I have a button in a form. It looks like this:

```
  .form-actions
    %buttons= f.submit t(:sign_up), :class => "cmply_btn btn", :disable_with => t(:form_disable)
```

What I am trying to do is to change the copy of the button to something in my YAML setup.

My yaml is located at config/locales/file_name.en.yml

How do I change the form button to some custom text that is setup that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure but you can try the following:

1- Follow similar pattern to this question: [Getting submit button label to be "Create model" instead of "Update model" inside form_for in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169011/getting-submit-button-label-to-be-create-model-instead-of-update-model-insid)

2- Use string instead of symble for translation. Use t("sign_up")

3- Try renaming the file to en.yml and put it in a separate folder if you have other ones

4- Move the f.submit to new line

```
%buttons
  = submit t("sign_up")...
```